# Python How to split a packet to extract data

Tags: python, split

I have a packet and I need to split it so that I can extract information from it. The packet is in string format and looks like this:

`{"S.No":"9","data":[{"id":"ID1","value":" 0.34"},{"id":"ID2","value":" 2.92"},{"id":"ID3","value":" 2.92"}]}`

From the above packet I need to extract the values of the `id` like for `ID1` value `0.34`

How can I extract all the values.

Thanks

Comment: What had you try now?

Comment: try list comprehension: `[a['id'] for a in str['data']]` or `[a['value'] for a in str['data'] if a['id'] == 'ID1']`

Comment: @timgeb Initially the data was in bytes like `(b'{"S.No":"9",...` then I used `data.decode("utf-8")` to convert it to string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly you can try something like:

```
import json
string_data = '{"S.No":"9","data":[{"id":"ID1","value":" 0.34"},{"id":"ID2","value":" 2.92"},{"id":"ID3","value":" 2.92"}]}'
data = json.loads(string_data)
[float(d['value']) for d in data['data']]
# will result in:
[0.34, 2.92, 2.92]
```

Comment: Exactly my thought. Best way to deal with this imo.